# Get osql output in command prompt

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following code to execute osql command and then get its output (like 2 rows affected etc) but it never finishes.
Please let me know what am I missing.

```
string sqlFilePath = Helper.GetFilePath(sqlFileName, Environment.CurrentDirectory);

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"osql -E -S @Server -d @Database -T -n -i ""@SqlFile"""
           .Replace("@Server", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"])
           .Replace("@Database", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DB))
           .Replace("@SqlFile", sqlFilePath);
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, you should use `sqlcmd` instead of the old, deprecated `osql/isql`

Comment: I have the same thought as marc_s.  sqlcmd is the 2013 (year) and the 2005+ (sql server version) way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might be running into two separate problems:

- Set the `FileName` and `Arguments` properties like this:

  ```
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "osql.exe";
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-E -S @Server -d @Database -T -n -i ""@SqlFile"""
      .Replace("@Server", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"])
      .Replace("@Database", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DB))
      .Replace("@SqlFile", sqlFilePath);
  ```
- You might also encounter an encoding issue. make sure that you save you *.sql* file by using the **Unicode Encoding (codepage 1200)** ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185330/issues-running-scripts-through-osql-exe)'s a question which describes the issue).